# Leaking condensate drain port on tankless water heater

Tags: plumbing, hvac

I have a Tagaki T-H3-DV-N tankless gas water heater that is leaking from the condensate drain port. The port is not plugged, but the water is coming through two holes that are in the plastic port itself (above the threads that receive the brass fitting for attaching a drain line). Any advice is appreciated.

[image]